# Дважды записывает данные в бд, почему?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

Значит так, речь идет о платежной системе (для личных нужд). Передаются на страницу "success" зашифрованный $_GET с параметрами, я сравниваю параметры, если все хорошо, то сохраняю в базу данных, вот только он сохраняет дважды, почему так может происходить?

Если коротко, то код примерно следующий:

```
if( $params['status'] == 1){
    $email = $params['email'];
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    $insert = 'INSERT INTO xxx (email) VALUES ("'.$email.'")';
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $insert) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Как можно проверить, отправились ли данные, чтобы не отправлять дважды? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте PDO

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;port=$db_port;dbname=$db_database", $db_user, $db_pass);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$link->exec("set names utf8");


$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO xxx (`email`) VALUES (:email)");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Да, забыл написать, что вместе с сохранением в базу данных, отправляется письмо mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
и тоже дважды

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан взглянуть бы на скрипт. На вскидку только можно сказать, что где-то метод вызывается дважды почему-то. Можно попробовать удалить параметр status из бд и тогда проверка не пройдет во второй раз. Но лучше выяснить что именно это вызывает

Comment: Предположим я рестартнул страницу, он же отправит данные.. в основном вопрос состоит в том, как проверить, отправлялись ли уже, чтобы не дублировать отправку

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан делаем запрос к этой таблице по такому email. Если есть - не вставлять. Вот такую проверку предлагаю

Comment: Окей , спасибо!